# VBA create pivot table for xlsx with more than 69,000 rows

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to VBA programming and currently what to create pivot tables for several xlsx/xls files. Some files have more than 70,000 instances.

```
'Create Pivot Table for PAX Traffic for each subclasses

Range("A1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select

Dim SourceRange As Range
Set SourceRange = Selection
Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Sheets.Add
    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create( _
    SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
    SourceData:=SourceRange, _
    Version:=xlPivotTableVersion11).CreatePivotTable _
    TableDestination:="Sheet1!R3C1", TableName:="PivotTable1" _
        , DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion11
```

It works well until those xlsx file with more than 70,000 instances.

Thanks for your gentle help.

Comment: I assume with the large files you are getting some sort of error or crashing.  Can you describe exactly what happens on the files it does not work for?

Comment: Can you describe how it "does not work well" for these larger files? Do you get an error message?

Comment: Hi it shown up following error message

Run-time error "13!" Type mismatch

Comment: Let me look at your excel . can u upload the sheet somewhere and provide the link

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Sub CreatePivot()
Dim pt1 As PivotTable
Dim ptcache1 As PivotCache

Dim trange As Range
Dim srange As Range

Set srange = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
Set trange = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")


Set ptcache1 = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(xlDatabase, srange)
Set pt1 = ptcache1.CreatePivotTable(trange, "do_Amazing")


With pt1
.PivotFields("...PivotFields1...").Orientation = xlRowField
.PivotFields("...PivotFields2...").Orientation = xlDataField
End With
```

Comment: Hi Sathish K, Thanks for your reply.

What is "do_Amazing" means?

I modified my code according to your reference.
While it stills shown up Run-time error "13!" Type mismatch until it do operation for the file with more than 70,000 instnaces.

It hide light the following code
    Set ptcache1 = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create( _
                        SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
                        SourceData:=SourceRange, _
                        Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14)

Comment: Do_Amazing - Name of pivot table .. Have u tried my above code

Comment: Sathish, I do tried your code and it shown the run-time error 13<br/>How can i type the modified code in comment?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this problem by turning the Range into an Excel Table (called ListObject in VBA).

Then, I passed the Excel Table instead of the Range as the source  to `PivotCaches.Create()`.

And it just worked.